# Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project add resx file to .net core project file (csproj) programmatically

Tags: c#, .net

I have a asp .net core project file (csproj). I’m trying to add some resource Files (resx) to the project programmatically. To add the resources I’m using nugget Microsoft.Build 16.3.0 
The application in which I’m trying to modify the project file is .net 4.7
It works almost perfect, but there is 1 problem, I can’t fix.

When I insert a new ProjectItem programmatically in xml it has the attribute  Include (Compile Include =…). When it’s added by Visual Studio, it has the attribute Update (Compile Update= …)
And when I try to compile the project, the error is:
Duplicate 'Compile' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Compile' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems.

The code to add to project looks like this:

```cs
project = new Project(CsProjectFullFileName);
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> metadataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
metadataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SubType", "Designer"));
metadataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LastGenOutput", Path.GetFileName(designerFullFileName)));
metadataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Generator", "ResXFileCodeGenerator"));
project.AddItem("EmbeddedResource", relativeResxName, metadataList);

string relativeDesignerName = HelperMethodesTimeJobMasken.GetRelativePath(designerFullFileName, CsProjectPath);

metadataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
metadataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DesignTime", "True"));
metadataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AutoGen", "True"));
metadataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DependentUpon", Path.GetFileName(resxFullFileName)));
project.AddItem("Compile", relativeDesignerName, metadataList);
```

The project File looks like this:

“PersonalienSqlQueries.resx” is added by Visual Studio
“Personalien2SqlRes.resx” is added programmatically.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <DockerTargetOS>Windows</DockerTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>
 
...
 
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="DataBase\Context\Personal\Personalien2\Personalien2SqlRes.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <LastGenOutput>Personalien2SqlRes.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="DataBase\Context\Personal\Personalien\PersonalienSqlQueries.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>PersonalienSqlQueries.resx</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="DataBase\Context\Personal\Personalien2\Personalien2SqlRes.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Personalien2SqlRes.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="DataBase\Context\Personal\Personalien\PersonalienSqlQueries.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <LastGenOutput>PersonalienSqlQueries.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    ....
  </ItemGroup>
....
</Project>
```